# Async requests to the context throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am adding an entity to the context via AddAsync() and then using SaveChangesAsync().However on the SaveChangesAsync() something goes wrong and it redirects me to the middleware I have set up for page not found. This is the method. Any suggestions are welcome .

```
public async Task<BeerDTO> CreateBeer(BeerDTO beerDTO)
    {
        if (this.context.Beers.Any(b => b.Name == beerDTO.Name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }


        var beer = new Beer()
        {
            Name = beerDTO.Name,
            StyleId = beerDTO.StyleId,
            BreweryId = beerDTO.BreweryId,
            ImagePath = beerDTO.ImagePath,
            Description = beerDTO.Description,
            ABV = beerDTO.ABV,
            CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

          await context.Beers.AddAsync(beer);

          await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        var beerToReturn = beer.GetDTO();

        return beerToReturn;
    }
```

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: It doesn't save and it redirects to the page not found View I have .

Comment: Could you try this for me instead; ```          context.Beers.Add(beer);

          await context.SaveChangesAsync(); ```

Comment: Sounds like there is an Exception happening, implement a try/catch and debug to see the error.

Comment: I tried what you said but I still don't get the exception type.Also the created beer is added to the database, because I can see it.

Comment: Well you said "*It doesn't save*" so I was commenting on bad information.If there are no errors during the execution of that method then the problem is somewhere further up the call chain.

Comment: Yup I found it, I didn't await the result from the CreateBeer service. Cheers !